# Como que faço para acessar o tamanho do texto(TexView) e comprimneto da caixa de texto (TextView) via código?

Tags: java, android

Estou querendo criar um `AutoScale TextView`, eu precisava acessar o tamanho do texto  e do comprimento via código.

Andei pesquisando pela internet encontrei bastante código de referente a ao tema da pergunta, pois eles são todos licenciado, mas eu gostaria de aprender e fazer meu próprio código.

Answer (score 2):

Para pegar o tamanho do texto via codigo use:

```
seuTextView.getText().length();
```

Para pegar o tamanho da fonte do texto via codigo use:

```
seuTextView.getTextSize();
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Att. Jeiferson

Comment: e para alterar seria `seuTextView.setTextSize();`