# TextView posicionar texto exibido sempre no final

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

Como fazer no `TextView` para que ao ir inserindo texto ele ficar como uma linha só e a caixa de texto ir acompanhado à medida que vai escrevendo?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Quando você vai inserindo texto no `TextView`, quando chega no fim da caixa texto ele vai inserindo e você não vê, eu quero fazer com que se veja o que vai sendo digitado, a parte inicial vai se escondendo e não ajustar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como que faço para acessar o tamanho do texto(TexView) e comprimneto da caixa de texto (TextView) via código?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107957/como-que-fa%c3%a7o-para-acessar-o-tamanho-do-textotexview-e-comprimneto-da-caixa-de)

Comment: @DiegoFelipe essa é outra pergunta, pois quando você vai inserindo texto no `TextView`, quando chega no fim da caixa texto ele vai inserindo e você não vê, eu quero fazer que veja o que sendo digitado a outra parte vai se escondendo e não ajustar na tela referente a outra pergunta

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para acrescentar detalhes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque por EditText

Conforme insere o texto você implementa o código abaixo junto

```
//posiciona o cursor no final do EditText
etReplicar.setSelection(etReplicar.getText().length());
```

No seu xml seu edit text deve ficar da seguinte forma para se comportar como um TextView

```
     <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/et_replicar" />
```

Comment: deu certo era isso queria, só um pergunta tem como voltar atrás só para visualizar o digitei.

Comment: arrastar com o dedo no touch n da?

Comment: você fez um pergunta, com o dedo no touch não deu,  mas não teria outro jeito?, tentei o  `horizontalScrollView`  mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Qual versão do android vc ta testando, eu fiz o teste aqui e consegui mover o conteudo para fazer a leitura? (eu testei na versão 4.1.1)

Comment: testei na versão 4.1.2 aparelho físico e no emulador 4.4, mas o que você fez ?,  só tocou com o dedo.

Comment: testei novamente deu certo mas ele vai travando, e não pega de primeira e tive que fazer um movimento aleatório puxando para horizontal depois para vertical  para o ver conteúdo.Tem uma maneira de melhorar isso ?